# htaccess redirect to parent page if not found with only knowing the beginning of path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have paths like this:

```
mypage/blog/somestring1
mypage/blog/somestring2
mypage/blog/somestring3
```

I would like it if I go to `mypage/blog/somestring1/page1` and it is not found it redirects back to: `mypage/blog/somestring1`.  All I know is that the path begins with mypage/blog.

One thing to note is that I am using Drupal and these are nodes with these path aliases.

The rest can be anything. Is it possible to create this 301 redirect if not found in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in `/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(blog/[\w-]+)/[\w-]+/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Actually I'm doing this in Drupal so I can't do it in that folder. Can I just update it to ...(mysite.com/blog...)?

Comment: You can use same rule in root .htaccess as well. Just make sure there is no .htaccess in `/blog/`

Comment: It works but it always redirects. I want to only redirect if not found. For example if I do actually have a path mypage/blog/somestring4/page1.  I don't want it to redirect to mypage/blog/somestring4.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` ensures that redirect happens only for request that is not for a real file/directory. Is `mypage/blog/somestring3` a real file?

Comment: It's not a real file. It's a drupal path that uses path alias: mypage/blog/somestring4/page1

Comment: ok then how to know if it is not-found path or real path? mod_rewrite only works by checking existing files/directories

Comment: I think it just isn't possible to do this with .htaccess but have to implement in Drupal.

Comment: Yes that's right. There will some kind of 404 hook in Drupal like other CMS e.g. WP where this needs to be handled in PHP code.